# Can I play an instant mid attack/block

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I attacked with 4/4 creature with first strike and life link.

My hubby blocked with his only card, a 2/2 with “when this creature is dealt damage, it deals 5 damage to target creature an opponent controls”. He chose to deal that damage to my attacking creature.

Can I then play an instant to give my creature +2/+2, so his damage does not kill my creature? (My attacking creature is 4/4).

Comment: Read up on how the stack works in the linked question. Th combat phase is not relevant to your question; you are basically asking if you are allowed to respond to a triggered ability with an instant, and the answer is yes.

Comment: Also, the damage still kills your creature, since there is also the combatdamage to be considered. 2 + 5 = 7 > 6 = 4 + 2

Comment: @ErikLohmann No, because the 4/4 has first strike, the 2/2 will never deal combat damage.

Comment: Yeah, skipped that part, sorry.